# Minimal "triangulation"

Tags: computational-geometry

I have a list of 9 points in $\mathbb{R}^4,$ and I'd like to know the "minimal triangulation" of the convex hull of these points, i.e. the minimal number of 4-dim simplices such that their union gives the convex hull of my points.

In dim 2, for example, the 2-dim simplex is a triangle, and, given 4 points such that not any 3 of them lie on the same line, the program should return 2. (The minimal triangulation of a parallelogram is 2 triangles)

I'm struggling with writing the program. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please add sample data to work with, and show what you tried so far.